# Extend length of border css

Tags: css, html, border

How do I expand the length of a border past the length of my text? This is what I have so far:

```
    color: #8C4600;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
```

This is the HTML:  `<li class = "vendors">VENDORS</li>`

Comment: Please post the html that is styled by this css.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "past the length of my text"?

Comment: What I mean, is that I have a line of text, then I have a bottom border, sort of line an underline, and the line of the border only goes as far as my text does, I want the border length to be longer than my text length.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

CSS borders are placed between the margins and padding of an HTML element.  If you want the borders of an HTML element to extend past the width (or height) of that element, you can add CSS padding to the element in order to push the borders outward.

For example, if your html is `<li class=vendors">VENDORS</li>` adding `padding:0 10px;` to your CSS would push the borders outwards on the right and left by 10px.

Answer (score 25):

Use padding and negative margins.

E.g.:

```
div {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 -1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

The above gives padding on all sides, and negative 1em margin on left and right. You may wish to fiddle w/ that.

Answer (score 0):

```css
   .inner {
        width: 80%;
    }
    
    .outer {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
        color: #8C4600;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p class="inner">Your text</p>
</div>
```

You will probably need to set the outer width though. As it might not auto-scale correctly in each browser. Or just make outer 120%, and inner a fixed width. This should be possible in multiple approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Just expand your border to the `vw` instead of its parent element.

Here is what I mean:

```css
.vendors {
  width: 100vw;
  border-bottom: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
}
```

```html
<li class="vendors">VENDORS</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find the answer to this too, hopefully I'm answering the intended question...Using a list (li) as an example...

```
li{
    border-style:solid;
    width:200px; /* this allows extension of border past text */
}
```

If you want, you could also align the text differently with stuff like

```
    text-align: center;
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to specify `"border: ##px color;`  in css.

This will create a border around the related html tag.

A sample code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <style>
     p {
       width:225px;
       border-style:solid;
       border:2px solid red;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

By default, without the width and border-style, the border will occupy 100% of the space. You can restrict its width and style in any way you want.

Here's [a link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) To a website that will help you the most.